# Regex PCRE: skip the first n occurences?

Tags: regex, pcre, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

When using PCRE regex, is there a way to skip the first n occurences? I saw some examples with \K but I don't understand how to use it.

The goal is to find "px" values, so this is the regex I use:

```
(?!1px)(\d+)(px)
```

(?!1px) is used to ignore "1px".

Considering the following sample string, how could I skip the first (**12px**), or second (**4px**) match, to match only the third (**2px**)?

```
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; font-size: 12px; color: #555;}

.test {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    box-shadow:  #aaa 4px 2px 6px;
    width: 36px;
    height: 24px;
}
```

Comment: Or, `(?s)^(?:.*?\b(?!1p)\d+px){2}.*?\K\b(?!1p)\d+px`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/1xiKed/1/).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew As the OP is mentioning first (12px), or second (4px), I think your answer is correct. You could post it :-)

Comment: The one from Wiktor Stribiżew works fine, even when I change the {x} value, in order to change how many occurences to skip. The one given by The fourth bird returns strange results when changing {x} value.
But both of them loose my capturing groups (\d+)(px), and I need them (sorry, I should have been more accurate in my question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
(?s)^(?:.*?\b(?!1p)\d+px){2}.*?\K\b(?!1p)(\d+)(px)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1xiKed/2)

**Details**

- `(?s)` - DOTALL `s` flag that makes `.` match line break chars, too
- `^` - start of a string
- `(?:.*?\b(?!1p)\d+px){2}` - exactly two occurrences of any 0 or more chars, as few as possible, and then 1+ digits + `px` but `1px` value
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars, as few as possible
- `\K` - [match reset operator](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html) discarding the text matched so far
- `\b` - word boundary
- `(?!1p)` - no `1p` allowed immediately to the right
- `(\d+)(px)` - 1+ digits captured in Group 1 and `px` captured in Group 2.

Comment: @Zax
If you would prefer to operate not in terms of "skip n occurences" but in terms of "find n-th occurence" then you can use:
```^(?s)(?:.*?\b\K(?!1p)(\d+)(px)){3}```
Now the number in figure brackets {3} means "match 3-th occurence".